# nodejs promise best way to implement from settimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, request-promise

I have the following functions working in nodejs, but  I am using a setTimeout rather than a promise.  If the createchange takes longer than the timeout I have, my code fails but does not catch the error correctly.

How would I substitute or change the following function(s) to work with a promise, so deploychange waits for createchange to complete, before continuing through the code?

I've tried a couple things but nothing seems to work.  Not sure which function I should redo either for the most effective solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

First function

```
function createchange(accessToken){
        const data = {
            templateName: "Template 1",
            summary: "Deploy  Change",

            configurationItems: [
              config_item
            ],
            wasEnvUsedForTesting: false,
            environment: test_env
          };

        rp({
            url: dbConfig.cmas_url,
            resolveWithFullResponse: true,
            method: 'POST',
            json: true,
            auth: {
            bearer: accessToken
            },
            body: data,
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'apikey': dbConfig.consumer_key,
            },
        }, function(err, res) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err.body);
            }else{
                console.log(res.body);
                crq = res.body.changeid;
            }

        });
    }
```

2nd  function

```
  function run() {
           deploychange();
          setTimeout(function(){ deployinsert(); }, 7500);
           deployrun();
      }
```

3rd function

```
        function deploychange (callback) {
        if (req.body.deployEnv == "PRD"){
          getToken(function(accessToken) {
          createchange(accessToken);   
          })}; 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the request-promise documentation, rp returns a promise.

You can actually convert your createChange function to return a promise like so:

```
const createchange = accessToken => {
    const data = {
        templateName: 'Template 1',
        summary: 'Deploy  Change',

        configurationItems: [config_item],
        wasEnvUsedForTesting: false,
        environment: test_env
    };

    return rp({
        url: dbConfig.cmas_url,
        resolveWithFullResponse: true,
        method: 'POST',
        json: true,
        auth: {
            bearer: accessToken
        },
        body: data,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            apikey: dbConfig.consumer_key
        }
    });
};
```

You can then call your function with the await keyword.

```
await createchange(accessToken);
```

Make sure that the function using await is marked with async

You can also write it like this:

```
createchange(accessToken)
    .then(({changeId}) => {
        // Do someth with the changeId
    })
    .catch(/* Error handling */)
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot Bastien with using async.  Can I still call my changeId by using data.body.changeId?

Comment: Sure, the createChange function will return the `res` part of the classic callback function. The `err` part will be thrown/catch. So you can basically do:
`const res = await createchange(accessToken);` and access to `res.body.changeid`

Comment: @Spring_Reboot, you need further information to solve your problem. In summary, `deploychange()` should return Promise and in order to do so, `getToken()` must be "promisified". Returning Promise from `createChange()` is only part of the solution.